# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre alias de una consulta desde nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente script desde la base de datos en MYSQL:

```
SELECT art.DESCRIPTION AS AREA_DESCRIPTION, ifunct.DESCRIPTION AS FUNCTIONAL_AREA_NAME, dirt.DESCRIPTION AS CONFIGURATION_NAME, cust.DESCRIPTION, itct.${`STATUS`}, cust.CHANGED_BY, cust.CHANGED_DATE, count.DESCRIPTION AS COUNTRY_DEPENDENCY 
    FROM itabcust cust 
    INNER JOIN (iarea ar INNER JOIN iareat art ON art.AREA = ar.AREA AND art.${`LANGUAGE`} = "ES") 
    ON ar.AREA = cust.AREA 
    INNER JOIN (ifunc_areat ifunct INNER JOIN ifunc_area ifunc ON ifunc.FUNCTIONAL_AREA = ifunct.FUNCTIONAL_AREA AND  ifunct.${`LANGUAGE`}="ES") 
    ON ifunc.FUNCTIONAL_AREA = cust.FUNCTIONAL_AREA 
    INNER JOIN (itabdir dir INNER JOIN itabdirt dirt ON dirt.TABLE_NAME = dir.TABLE_NAME AND dirt.${`LANGUAGE`}="ES" AND dir.TABLE_TYPE = "C") 
    ON dir.TABLE_NAME = cust.TABLE_NAME 
    INNER JOIN (ccountry coun INNER JOIN ccountryt count ON count.CCOUNTRY = coun.COUNTRY AND count.${`LANGUAGE`}="ES") 
    ON coun.COUNTRY = cust.COUNTRY 
    LEFT JOIN (itc_status itc INNER JOIN itc_statust itct ON itct.${`STATUS`} = itc.${`STATUS`} AND itct.${`LANGUAGE`}="ES") ON itc.${`STATUS`} = cust.${`STATUS`}
```

Y esta fracción de código donde "dibujo" los datos:

```
export default class configuration {
    prueba() {
        axios.post('/search/configuration')
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                //los tr > td
                let tr = ''
                
                result.data.map((elemento,indice) => {
                let STATUS=elemento.STATUS!=null?elemento.STATUS:'', 
                CHANGED_BY=elemento.CHANGED_BY!=null?elemento.CHANGED_BY:'',
                DESCRIPTION= elemento.DESCRIPTION!=null?elemento.DESCRIPTION:'',
                CHANGED_DATE=elemento.CHANGED_DATE!=null?elemento.CHANGED_DATE:''
                
                    tr += `<tr>
                            <td>${elemento.AREA_DESCRIPTION}</td>
                            <td>${elemento.FUNCTIONAL_AREA_NAME}</td>
                            <td><a href="">${elemento.CONFIGURATION_NAME}</a></td>
                            <td>${DESCRIPTION}</td>
                            <td>${STATUS}</td>
                            
                            <td><strong>${CHANGED_BY}</strong>-${CHANGED_DATE}</td>
                            <td>${elemento.COUNTRY_DEPENDENCY}</td>
                        </tr>`
                })
                $("#tableConfiguration tbody").html(tr)
                $("#tableConfiguration").dataTable()

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Pero necesito tomar los nombres de las columnas, tal cual como se traen desde la base de datos, usarlos  como títulos en el `<thead>`. No tengo la menor idea de como hacerlo, la consulta no se puede cambiar. El código está hecho completamente en nodejs.

Comment: Ya tienes los nombres de todas las columnas en _elemento.NOMBRE_DE_COLUMNA_, ¿qué es lo que falta hacer?

Comment: Pero es retornar el nombre como tal de la consulta, ejemplo, en la parte superior del query dice  ifunct.DESCRIPTION AS FUNCTIONAL_AREA_NAME, en este caso requeriría FUNCTIONAL_AREA_NAME, incluso en el caso deque no fuese un alias pudiese ser DESCRIPTION de ifunc. Esto lo necesitamos así con el fin de que imprima estas columnas con el idioma seleccionado previamente en la cuenta de usuario.